# templated constructor vs. templated copy constructor

Tags: c++, templates, constructor, c++11, copy-constructor

I have a class with a templated constructor for implicit move conversion, however this constructor should NOT be used for the class (which should only be copy constructible). However, the compiler always tries to use the templated constructor instead of the regular copy constructor.

e.g. With this i get the follow compiler errors, [link](http://pastebin.com/ZHsDTQ12). (you can just copy paste this code if you want to try it)

```
struct implementation{};
class my_class
{
 my_class(my_class&&); // delete move-constructor... OUCH... COMPILER ERROR
public:
 my_class(){}
 my_class(const my_class& other) : impl_(other.impl_){}

 template<typename T>
 my_class(T&& impl) : impl_(std::make_shared<T>(std::move(impl))){} // Still tries to use this...

private:
 std::shared_ptr<implementation> impl_;
};

class other_class
{
public:
 my_class foo()
 { 
       return instance_; // Wants to use move-constructor???
 }
private:
 my_class instance_;
};
```

Any one got an idea how to solve this properly?

Comment: You have reference, to reference? o_O

Comment: It is called rvalue-reference, see http://www.artima.com/cppsource/rvalue.html.

Comment: Yeah, `&&` now means "logical and" resp. "rvalue reference", depending on context. Isn't token recycling *awesome*? :)

Comment: And isn't it C++0x feature? I don't see C++0x in tags.

Comment: @Pawel: Good point, edited tags.

Comment: Your line that says "delete move-constructor"... doesn't.  "Deleting" a constructor in C++0x means something very specific, and move constructors don't even make sense before C++0x.

Comment: That looks like a poor design. It will sooner or later come to slice objects off the implementation base. It seems you cannot make this work with moving in a safe way (i.e so it doesn't slice).

Comment: *Sigh* I'm going to need another five years to learn C++0x. haha

Comment: @Johannes. Where can the slice occur?

Comment: Have you seen my updated code that works with both kinds of references?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Okay, here is my complete overhaul of `my_class`:

```
class my_class
{
public:
    my_class() {}
    my_class(my_class&& that) : impl_(std::move(that.impl_)) {}

    template <typename T> my_class(T&& impl,
    typename std::enable_if<
        std::is_base_of<
            implementation,
            typename std::remove_reference<T>::type
        >::value,
        void
    >::type* dummy = 0
    ) : impl_(std::make_shared<T>(std::forward<T>(impl))) {}

    template <typename T>
    typename std::enable_if<
        std::is_base_of<
            implementation,
            typename std::remove_reference<T>::type
        >::value,
        my_class&
    >::type
    operator=(T&& impl)
    {
        std::make_shared<implementation>(std::forward<T>(impl)).swap(impl_);
        return *this;
    }

private:
    std::shared_ptr<implementation> impl_;
};
```

As suggested by others, this works for lvalue and rvalue references by using `std::forward` instead of `std::move`. The `remove_reference` is necessary because for lvalue references, `T` is a reference, and `derived&` does not derive from `base`, but `derived` does (note the reference).

Comment: @FredOverflow: Implicit conversion doesn't seem to work with your fix, please see my edit. Any ideas?

Comment: @ronag: From the error message, it seems you need to provide a move assignment operator.

Comment: @FredOverflow: I've tried that. Also tried foo_ = my_class(std::move(boo)); In which case I get "error C2440: '<function-style-cast>' : cannot convert from 'derived_1' to 'my_class'. No constructor could take the source type, or constructor overload resolution was ambiguous".

Comment: @ronag: I have updated my answer with a move assignment operator template. Now I need sleep :)

Comment: @ronag: Looks dangerous. Remember, `T&&` can also be an lvalue reference, and moving from them is not such a good idea. Also, you are missing `return *this;` at the end.

Comment: @FredOverflow. Good point. Updated to your version. Still same error though. Btw, I would up vote you a few more times if I could... Thx alot.

Comment: @ronag: Okay, I couldn't sleep :) Does the updated version work?

Comment: The constructor won't work since it will make a non-deduced context. Try putting the whole `enable_if` stuff into the `template<...>` clause as a default function template parameter or as a normal function default argument of a second function parameter.

Comment: @ronag @Johannes @jpalecek I have updated my answer, feedback welcome.

Comment: @Fred I believe only the first nick in that list receives the notification :( I wonder whether you can trick SO tho by editing the comment, shuffling the @'es around so everytime a different nick is at the front.

Comment: @Johannes: I gave it a try, let's see what happens :) By the way, where can I read more about this "non-deduced context" stuff? Or is that too trivial? :)

Comment: @Fred see 14.8.2.4 in teh spec (the corresponding section of n3225 is more detailed tho, you may be better off looking there).

Comment: @FredOverflow. One last problem, std::make_shared<implementation>(std::forward<T>(impl)).swap(impl_); doesn't work if "implementation" is abstract (which probably should be required as otherwise slicing could occur?).

Comment: @ronag: What exactly do you mean by "doesn't work"? Does not compile? Runtime crash? Does `implementation` have a virtual destructor?

Comment: @FredOverflow. Nvm. It works just fine. Dunno why I got compiler errors before.

Answer (score 2):

This can never work:

```
template<typename T>
my_class(typename std::enable_if<std::is_base_of<implementation, derived_1>::value, T&&>::type impl) : impl_(std::make_shared<T>(std::move(impl)))  {}

template <typename T> 
my_class& operator= (typename std::enable_if<std::is_rvalue_reference<T&&>::value && !std::is_same<T, my_class>::value, T&&>::type impl)
```

The reason is that you only use `T` in non-deduced contexts. Plainly speaking, the compiler cannot deduce `T` if the argument it should have deduce it from has the form `Anything<T>::type`.

So, if you want to use `enable_if` on assignment operator, you put it in the return value:

```
template <class T>
typename enable_if<..., T&>::type operator=(const T&);
```

in case of the conversion (should work for move, too) constructor, you add a dummy parameter with default value:

```
template <class T>
MyClass(const T&, typename enable_if<..., void>::type* =0);
```

FredOverflow already gave you the correct assignment operator.

BTW you needn't restrict it to rvalue-references, if you use `std::forward` instead of `std::move`. See [here](http://ideone.com/nmmqz). That would give you (copy&paste from FredOverflow):

```
template <typename T>
typename std::enable_if<std::is_base_of<implementation, T>::value, my_class&>::type
operator=(T&& impl)
{
    std::make_shared<implementation>(std::forward<T>(impl)).swap(impl_);
    return *this;
}
```